# Using shutil.move to move files

Tags: python, macos, file, move, shutil

I'm attempting to write a script to move a file from one location to another locally on a machine. I am writing this script for Mac OS.

Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import shutil
import _osx_support
import os

src = "Macintosh HD//Users//jerel//Desktop//Testing/"
dst = "Macintosh HD//Users//jerel//Desktop/"

shutil.move(src=src + "Testing doc 2.pdf", dst=dst)
```

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Macintosh HD//Users//jerel//Desktop//Testing/Testing doc 2.pdf' -> 'Macintosh HD//Users//jerel//Desktop/'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jerel/Desktop/moving files .py", line 11, in <module>
    shutil.move(src=src + "Testing doc 2.pdf", dst=dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Macintosh HD//Users//jerel//Desktop//Testing/Testing doc 2.pdf'
```

Updated code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import shutil
import _osx_support
import os

src = "/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing/"
dst = "/Users/jerel/Desktop/"

shutil.move(src=src + "Testing doc 2.pdf", dst=dst)
```

Update 2:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import shutil
import _osx_support
import os

src = "/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing/"
dst = "/Users/jerel/Desktop/"

shutil.move(src=src + "Testing doc 2", dst=dst)
```

```
Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing/Testing doc 2' -> '/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing doc 2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jerel/Desktop/moving files .py", line 11, in <module>
    shutil.move(src=src + "Testing doc 2", dst=dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 802, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing/Testing doc 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths should not include the 'Macintosh HD' instead it should just start with /Users

**Edit**: Also, change the double slashes in the path to single slashes

Comment: @rell7725 you are also using double slashes, even though you should just be using single slashes

Comment: Changed the slashes from double to single

Comment: @rell7725 Can you update your post with the updated code and errors?

Comment: @rell7725 Once the corrections are made to the path, I am unable to reproduce your issue, as the file moves just fine for me. Are you sure that the file 'Testing doc 2.pdf' exists in the specified directory?

Comment: Just realize when I went back into the folder for the source that file name is "Testing doc 2" and not with.pdf. It is just a pdf file. However, im still getting an error. Updating form with code and error

Comment: Which directory is the file in? This error can only mean that the file does not exist in the path you're providing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the shutil module properly. You can use the below command.

```
pip3 install pytest-shutil
```

Then use the following code.

```
import shutil

shutil.move(r"/Users/jerel/Desktop/Testing/Testing doc 2.pdf", r"/Users/jerel/Desktop")
```